# Javascript setting style's color, works in Firefox, not in Chrome, Safari etc

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Here is a minimal HTML page to turn the placeholder text red if a value is missing

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<input type="text", class="email", name="email", placeholder="initial placeholder text", size=48><br />
<button onClick="Validate()">
   Validate
</button>

<script>
function Validate() {
   var email = document.getElementsByClassName("email")[0];

   if (email.value.trim() == '') {
      email.placeholder = "Updated placeholder text";
      email.style.color = "red"; // for Firefox
   }
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

The placeholder text is updated on clicking the button if the field is left blank. In Firefox the font color goes red, in many other browsers nothing happens.
I've tried using all of these

```
email.style = "color: red"; // invalid but works in Firefox
email.setAttribute('style', 'color:red;');
email.style.setProperty('color', 'red');
```

and all work in FF, not in others.
`console.log(email.style.color);`
shows the value has been set.

Setting the *background* color works in all browsers! Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share your (relevant) [mcve] code in your question, including the html, css and JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks, but not needed because another poster has given a perfect solution and I have accepted it.

Comment: Now added.  But please note the questions has already been answered perfectly and I have accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the placeholder's color you're supposed to use the `::placeholder` selector in CSS. What is surprising here is that it actually works on FF.

Anyway, to solve your problem, I would recommand to use specific class to achieve this.

In your CSS:

```
input.invalid-value::placeholder{
    color: red;
}
```

Then in your JS:

```
if (email.value.trim() == '' || !ValidateEmail(email.value)) {
    email.classList.add('invalid-value');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerem!  Worked a treat - on Chromium.  But does nothing on Firefox!  Using this AND setting `email.style.color = "red";` seems to cover both (all?) browsers.

Comment: Sorry, you should add `opacity: 1;` for this to work on FF. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp)

Comment: Thanks again @Jerem.  Yes, with opacity: 1 in the CSS, Firefox also works without the workaround of adding `email.style.color = "red";`.  And still works on Chromium. Your link implies that Edge vers 12-18 may not be happy so I must test on that too.

Comment: Edge versions 12-18 are archaic and can probably be ignored.  Current version is 119!